# Nextjs: request to load a png/jpg image from local assets folder fails

Tags: next.js13

I need to load some images in my Nextjs repo. I am using the Image element from next/image link in this snippet

```
import Image from "next/image";
import MyImage from "@/assets/img/my-image.png";

export default function Comp(){
return  <Image src={MyImage} />
}
```

I get this error in the terminal

```
upstream image response failed for /_next/static/media/my-image.60e6ce02.png TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7188:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7516:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8) {
  cause: Error: [object Object]
      at makeNetworkError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6317:51)
      at httpNetworkFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7810:16)
      at async httpNetworkOrCacheFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7703:33)
      at async httpFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7557:37)
      at async schemeFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7489:18)
      at async node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7342:20
      at async mainFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7338:20) {
    [cause]: undefined
  }
}
```

And in the network tab

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fmy-image.f4be41c5.png&w=750&q=75
```

I have also tried to place the images in the public folder and in this case I use this snippet

```
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Comp(){
return  <Image
            src="/img/my-image.jpg"
            alt=""
            width={372}
            height={268}
          />
}
```

Again similar errors in terminal

```
upstream image response failed for /img/my-image.jpg TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7188:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7516:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8) {
  cause: Error: [object Object]
      at makeNetworkError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6317:51)
      at httpNetworkFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7810:16)
      at async httpNetworkOrCacheFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7703:33)
      at async httpFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7557:37)
      at async schemeFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7489:18)
      at async node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7342:20
      at async mainFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7338:20) {
    [cause]: undefined
  }
}
```

And in the network tab

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fmy-image.jpg&w=750&q=75
```

Strangely I am able to import svg files from the asset folder. In the network this is the Request url

```
http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/my-image.308008ef.svg
```

I have noticed that for images rather than svg, the request Url is different. But there is nothing in the nextjs config file. Any explanation/suggestion on how I can retrieve images?

I read the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the specific Nextjs version I am using.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53715

Upgrade to version 13.5.5 solved the issue